# renderWidget in view does nothing

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I'm trying to add a way for members to comment on articles. From what I have gathered, it should be as simple as using:

```
<?php echo $this->content()->renderWidget('modulename.widget-name') ?>
```

So this is my attempt in my view:

```
<div>

<?php
echo("<h2>".$this->news['title']."</h2>");

print_r($this->news['news']);

echo $this->content()->renderWidget('core.comment')

?>   

</div>
```

I only seem to get an empty `<div>` tag at the bottom of my page.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit: works for `'core.admin-dashboard'` but not `'core.comment'`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget core.comment will appear only if the page where you're placing this widget has subject and there is methods 'comments' and 'likes' for this subject:

```
if( !($subject instanceof Core_Model_Item_Abstract) ||
    !$subject->getIdentity() ||
    (!method_exists($subject, 'comments') && !method_exists($subject, 'likes')) ) {
  return $this->setNoRender();
}
```

Hope this helps.